# Extending AlertDialog creates big padding on the bottom of the dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a dialog which uses a custom view which also has a number of different behaviours attached, which is why I extended AlertDialog instead of using a builder.

The code that creates the view looks like this looks like this

```
class MyTaskCreateDialog extends AlertDialog implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    public MyTaskCreateDialog(Context ctx, TaskItem item, List<Person> people, IOnFinishListener listener) {
        super(ctx) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_my_task_create, null, false);
        setView(view);
        setCancelable(true);
        setOnCancelListener(this);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        assign_views(view); //this assigns the views to the local variables
        attach_listeners(); 
        refresh_view();//this updates the view with data
    }
```

the above uses this layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/app_padding">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/my_task_create_hint_title" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/my_task_create_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/my_task_create_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_task_create_title">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/my_task_create_hint_description" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_assignee_caption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_task_create_caption_assignee"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_task_create_assignee"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/my_task_create_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/my_task_create_assignee" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_assignee"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:checked="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_padding"
        android:textOff="@string/my_task_create_toggle_manually"
        android:textOn="@string/my_task_create_toggle_automatically"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/my_task_create_description"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/my_task_create_assignee_caption"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_task_create_description"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_spinner_item" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_create_task"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:text="@string/my_task_create_button_create"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/my_task_create_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_task_create_assignee" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_task_create_cancel"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:text="@string/my_task_create_button_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/my_task_create_create_task"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_task_create_assignee" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which creates a dialog with big padding at the bottom.

in fact is I change the background of the ConstraintLayout to be greyish, then the bottom half of the dialog seems to be the default color.

the result of the above looks like this:

[image: the dialog that is shown]

now I know that some space is saved for the buttons (I do not use those, I use custom ones from the layout file), but how can I make the rest of the space disappear and make my dialog wrap its content?

Comment: this @dimen/app_margin, how much is that? Try removing it, or using smaller value

Comment: I try your code from my end and it works fine. First I change all `app_margin` and `app_padding` to `10dp`, Secondly I remove `assign_views`, `attach_listeners` and `refresh_view` calls. So problems have to be in those place. Do `app_margin` too large, or you add anything in those methods. More code will help

Comment: app_margin and padding is 8dp, I'll try just loading the view and see what it looks like and add some more of my code

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and the only solution that worked for me is to add the following code into all `View`s inside of `ConstraintLayout`:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

Those sentences replace this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```